# Android App Link : Difference Build APK and Generate Signed APK

Tags: android, applinks

I am a little bit confused about two differents behavior and I would need some help.
I am working on an android application with App Links implemented.

I have configured my project to use a keystore for Released build version.

When I use **RUN Application** of Release version from Android Studio, my application will be opened as a deeplink (disambiguation dialog open when click on a link).
When I generate a **SIGNED APK** using the same keystore, my application is opened as an app link (direct to the app without dialog).
I have analyzed the two apps (**Build APK** & **SIGNED APK**):

- **RUN Application** : App Link status is in ask mode when application is installed;
- **Signed APK** : App Link status is in always mode when application is installed;

Is anyone could explain me what are the differences between RUN Application and Generate Signed APK which could lead to these two different behavior ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Build APK:** this is testing APK you can say.in this, we don't need to use Keystore. And in this build Keys are not restricted as we use in Google maps or Facebook SDK. Not big

**Signed APK:** This is purely a live build you can say. we use live credentials in this build we normally won't use this build for testing.we generate Signed APK after complete testing normal APK.

**BIG DIFFERENCE is that play store only accept the SIGNED APK.**

So we generate signed APK normally when we have to submit our app to play store.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you created the assetlinks.json using the **release keystore**.

Actually, in regards to app link, there is no difference between the **RUN Application(release build)** and the **Signed APK**.

The **verification of the `assetlinks.json`** file is done **during the app installation**. When you run the application from the android studio, the disambiguation dialog is showing because in the device, you might already have a pre-installed version of your app. So when you run the application, the app is not uninstalled and then installed. It just refreshes the code. So the assetlinks.json verification is not done.

So to test app links while running from android studio, **first uninstall the app from the device/emulator, and then try triggering app link**. The disambiguation dialog will not be shown.

You don't have to uninstall the app every time you want to run the application. But if you have changed the `assetlinks.json` file(at server side) or the manifest entry in manifest file, then uninstall the app and then run the application(release build) from android studio. The disambiguation dialog will not be shown.